PostgreSQL RDS instance upgraded 13->16; Seeing missing file message in logs constantly
I recently updated my RDS instance from PostgreSQL 13 to 16. Everything seems to be working perfectly, except I notice in my logs that I'm getting this message just about whenever a query executes:
skipping missing configuration file "/rdsdbdata/config/recovery.conf
From what I've read, recovery.conf is no more in recent versions of PostgreSQL, but I don't what to do to prevent this log message.
